# Why is there a loading spinner in my action bar and how do I remove it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

Basically I'm pretty new to android development but so far I've been able to fix every issue/bug I've had except this one (I've seen way worse, but for some reason this little bug takes all my time..).

Just for contact, I'm doing an application that loads local and external xml file and displays the content, fetch xml files from a server and save them locally, etc.

The issue I'm running into is the following; on older android phones (on 4.4 there is no issue, on 4.0 there is) when the application loads, I have a loading spinner icon in my action bar while the only place I use one is in another layout that is not referenced in my main activity. I figured maybe it's because I didn't initiate my menu correctly or something, but everything seems fine (and works on newer versions). I have a searchview that is working fine, a settings menu that is also fine, but for some reason there is always a spinning icon next to those elements.

I can edit this and add my layout/code if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe put `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false)` in `Activity`s `onCreate` ([check docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility%28boolean%29))